# What is localhost access log in tomcat?

Tags: tomcat

I want to know what is  local host access log in tomcat ? what information we can monitor by these logs and how to read them through a Java program?

Answer (score 13):

The access log contains the information for each request that hits the server. It can be used to track page hit counts, user session activity, and so on because it logs all the incoming requests along with Timestamp, Request HTTP Method and the HTTP Response code.

Sample log statements are as follows

```
46.181.252.151  - - [22/Feb/2019:19:04:19 +0000] "GET /task/768476366 HTTP/1.1" 200 6765
36.231.298.259  - - [22/Feb/2019:19:04:20 +0000] "GET /doc/wallet/9855563 HTTP/1.1" 200 45564
```

Common logging pattern ="%h %l %u %t "%r" %s %b"

```
%h – Remote hostname (or IP address if the resolveHosts attribute is set to false; by default the value is false).
%l – Remote logical user name; this is always a hyphen (-).
%u – Remote user that has been authenticated. In the example, “admin” and a hyphen (-). If there is none, it’s a hyphen (-).
%t – Date and time in common log file format.
%r – The first line of the request. In the example, “GET / HTTP/1.1” (note that this is configured to be shown within quotes (“”)).
%s – The HTTP status code of the response. In the example 200 is the OK status.
%b – Bytes sent count, excluding HTTP headers, and shows a hyphen (-) if zero.
```

For more details [click here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/tomcat/tomcat-access-log-configuration-example/)

Answer (score 7):

`localhost access log` in tomcat contains the information associated with a request i.e.:

1. IP address
2. Time
3. Request method (GET or POST)
4. The resource for which the request is coming.

Answer (score 2):

As the name suggests , `access logs` are special kind of logs that contain information regarding logging and usage activity of any resource from an host.

I would strongly suggest that you go through the documentation of it [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/valve.html)

> how to read them through a Java program

IMO, Reading `access logs` of a certain application might not be a good idea due to some obvious reasons. But then again , if you really must read them, they are simple files residing in the `$TOMCAT_DIR$/logs` folder and you can perform regular IO on them. Just be sure to verify file locks and read/write permissions on them.

*Just a hitch:* You wont be able to read the file that is being used by tomcat for a particular day.

Comment: What is the minimum duration of logging? Last month in my localhost access log the tomcat is logging every minute in a day with local ip address. This month i have seen that the difference between two consecutive logs is more than 1 hour and it happened through out the month. Why it is not writing ever minute ? Do you have any idea?