# Log all HTTP requests of Tomcat Server?

Tags: tomcat, logging, request

Is it possible to print all requests to Tomcat and responses from Tomcat in a logfile?

ex:

> > request
> >
> > headers: [header1=a, header2=a]
> >
> > params: [param1=avv, param2=b]
> >
> > response
> >
> > status-code = 200
> >
> > response = its works

Comment: Have a look at your server.xml for pattern in access.log for response status. To get header and other details, you might need to write your own valve.

Comment: For developers using IntelliJ IDEA, enabling "Tomcat Localhost Access Log" in [Logs tab § Run/Debug Configuration: Tomcat Server](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-tomcat-server.html#logsTab) may help you see the summary about incoming requests. And you may also want to know [What is localhost access log in tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20784453).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Put an `AccessLogValve` in the `Host` or `Context` element e.g.:

```
<Host name="www.mysite.com" appBase="..." >

    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
     directory="logs" prefix="mysitelog." suffix=".txt" 
     pattern="..." resolveHosts="false" />

</Host>
```

The `pattern` attribute can take one of two shorthand values (*common*,*combined*) or a custom pattern using a number of constants and replacement strings. Let me quote the Tomcat docs:

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve

> Values for the pattern attribute are made up of literal text strings,
>   combined with pattern identifiers prefixed by the "%" character to
>   cause replacement by the corresponding variable value from the current
>   request and response. The following pattern codes are supported:
>
> ```
> %a - Remote IP address
> %A - Local IP address
> %b - Bytes sent, excluding HTTP headers, or '-' if zero
> %B - Bytes sent, excluding HTTP headers
> %h - Remote host name (or IP address if enableLookups for the connector is false)
> %H - Request protocol
> %l - Remote logical username from identd (always returns '-')
> %m - Request method (GET, POST, etc.)
> %p - Local port on which this request was received. See also %{xxx}p below.
> %q - Query string (prepended with a '?' if it exists)
> %r - First line of the request (method and request URI)
> %s - HTTP status code of the response
> %S - User session ID
> %t - Date and time, in Common Log Format
> %u - Remote user that was authenticated (if any), else '-'
> %U - Requested URL path
> %v - Local server name
> %D - Time taken to process the request, in millis
> %T - Time taken to process the request, in seconds
> %F - Time taken to commit the response, in millis
> %I - Current request thread name (can compare later with stacktraces)
> ```
>
> There is also support to write information incoming or outgoing
>   headers, cookies, session or request attributes and special timestamp
>   formats. It is modeled after the Apache HTTP Server log configuration
>   syntax. Each of them can be used multiple times with different xxx
>   keys:
>
> ```
> %{xxx}i write value of incoming header with name xxx
> %{xxx}o write value of outgoing header with name xxx
> %{xxx}c write value of cookie with name xxx
> %{xxx}r write value of ServletRequest attribute with name xxx
> %{xxx}s write value of HttpSession attribute with name xxx
> %{xxx}p write local (server) port (xxx==local) or remote (client) port (xxx=remote)
> %{xxx}t write timestamp at the end of the request formatted using the enhanced SimpleDateFormat pattern xxx
> ```

As you can see there are quite a few fields that can be used, but if you still need more, you have to write your own `AccessLogValve` implementation.

Comment: No support for logging *all* headers ? (which was basically the question asked)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17545691/how-to-log-all-headers-of-request-response-in-tomcat-7

Comment: @peterh: based on requestdumper for tomcat 6 and 7+ with example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54595660/1915920

Comment: Is it possible to log if the request came through HTTP or HTTP? (Assuming I configured both Connectors)

Answer (score 15):

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#Request_Dumper_Filter

The Request Dumper Filter logs information from the `request` and `response` objects and is intended to be used for debugging purposes.

The following entries in a web application's `web.xml` would enable the Request Dumper filter for all requests for that web application.

If the entries were added to `CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml`, the Request Dumper Filter would be enabled `for all web applications`.

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>requestdumper</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.apache.catalina.filters.RequestDumperFilter
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>requestdumper</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.The Request Dumper provides a LOT of information about each request, maybe too much, but I would prefer this much information if I'm debugging. Just be aware of the need to remove it when you're done debugging, unless you want some very large log files. 

Comment: remember to add the logging configuration as explained in the documentation http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/filter.html#Request_Dumper_Filter . This part has been essential for me to have it working under tomcat9: "The following entries in CATALINA_BASE/conf/logging.properties ..."

Comment: Do you know if I need to execute something special if the tomcat is hosted on a windows server? I mean I am able to use the filter when the server is Linux but when trying with windows it is not creating the request-dumper file. But I am not sure if it is because of my application configuration, by the way, the app is SAP BO BI.

Comment: This logs a bunch of garbage. NOT a HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

[David Lee](http://robobruin.blogspot.com/2007/09/logging-request-and-response-headers-in.html) says add this to your `server.xml`:

`<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestDumperValve"/>`

but, I guess that is tomcat 6; this answer shows how to use `Request_Dumper_Filter` in tomcat 7 https://stackoverflow.com/a/8727615/1763984