# How to I log the subaddress of HTTP request

Tags: python, django, http

I am trying to make a simple web server. For example, when trying to visit website `wordpress/mywebsite/thisiswhatIwanttorecord`  the backend will record the `thisiswhatIwanttorecord` part in a DB or even just txt file and return a standard error page no matter what the suburl is.
Does anyone know how to do this in Python Django? Thanks!

Seems like it could be as easy as changing a config file for example in Tomcat. [Log all HTTP requests of Tomcat Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34094030/log-all-http-requests-of-tomcat-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often add a middleware to log whatever i want (include request data, response data).

Here's the sample middleware:

```
class RequestLogMiddleware(object):

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        self.log_request(request, response)
        return response

    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        response = type('', (), {})()
        response.status_code = 500
        response.exception = response.content = exception
        self.log_request(request, response)

    def log_request(self, request, response):
        # Log request and response to file or db here
        print(request, response)
```