# Large localhost_access_log files filling up the Tomcat application server

Tags: tomcat

My server is filling up the local disk drive and it's because of the Tomcat Application Server Logs. What are these files? Can their location be changed? Can they be safely deleted?

thanks,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete Tomcat Access Log after n days?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772021/how-to-delete-tomcat-access-log-after-n-days)

Comment: Check also [What is localhost access log in tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20784453/11748454).